# What's the difference between the main deck and top deck of the Empire State Building?

Tags: tickets, sightseeing, new-york-city, landmarks

Is there a significant difference in these two? Anything special to experience in 102nd floor? I believe the view of both floors don't have a significant difference. Apart from the view what are the main difference between these? There are two types of tickets which allows to 86th only and 86th and 102nd both.

Answer (score 14):

The biggest difference between [main deck: 86th floor](http://www.esbnyc.com/explore/main-deck-86th-floor) and [top deck: 102nd floor](http://www.esbnyc.com/explore/top-deck-102nd-floor) is that main deck is open air observatory and top deck is much smaller room enclosed by glass. As question mentions the view of these floor isn't significantly different, many articles claim *[the view is largely same](http://loving-newyork.com/empire-state-building-is-it-worth-going-up-to-the-102nd-floor/)*, [just a little higher](http://snappingtheglobe.com/?tag=empire-state-building).